# Compilando trasnformación: El caracter no es válido en Visual Basic

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net

les vengo a exponer mi problema, cuando creo un proyecto de Windows Form App (.NET Framework) con Visual Basic, a la hora de importar mi modelo de datos desde SQLServer , parece como que se me importa pero me da un error de compilacióm, me añade esta linea de codigo en el fichero **EF6.Utility.VB.ttinclude**:

`_generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment");`

Me dice que es error de sintaxis ya que en VB no acepta los puntos y coma ( ; )

Si intento borrar esa linea de código me hace guardar el cambio en la carpetade Visual Studio la cual no tengo permisos como es obvio, he probado en otro ordenador que tengo y no me da ningún problema y no me sale esto.

Sera culpa de la Base de Datos? Del Visual Studio? Que quiza me faltará por configurar algo?

Ayudadme por favor, muchas gracias de antemano. Espero haberme explicado mínimamente bien